# How to login a user on Uber partner app before getting whitelisted?

Tags: uber-api

I registered an app on developer.uber.com and I'm able to fetch basic-data such as products, time-estimates and fare-estimates. When i go about authenticating a user to get access-token, I get an "invalid_client_id' in response on using 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize'. This is totally obvious as my app is not on your whitelist of partner apps. But I need to tryout the bearer-centric endpoints as well.

So, my question is - how do I login a user on a sandbox app?